# CORS Error for using infura

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura

I need to call the balance function from my smart contract using my application and i don't want to use metamask and other web3 providers like infua as I am not going to send any transactions and don't need to use only the public wallet ID

It worked perfectly on localHost and some browsers but its failing on the most of the browsers due to CORS preflight error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Balance Checker</title>

    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="display"></h1>
    <input id="wallet_add" type="text">
    <button id="button">Check Balance</button> 
    <input id="amount" type="number">
    <button id="withdraw">Withdraw Tokens</button>
    <h1 id = "status"></h1>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/71cda5338d4440fa9cd615a82b829d47"));
    }

    var P1Contract =  web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"end_ICO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"releaseICO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"total_Supply","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"ico_startdate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"StopICO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"start_PREICO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_price_tokn","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"pre_startdate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"start_ICO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"ico_enddate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_totalsupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"stage","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"pre_enddate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]);
    var P1 = P1Contract.at('0x080eB7238031F97Ff011e273D6CaD5ad0c2dE532');
    console.log(P1);

    $("#button").click(function() {
        var ame = P1.balanceOf($('#wallet_add').val());
        var name = ame.toNumber();
        var balanc = name / 100000000;
        console.log(balanc);
        $("#display").html(balanc);
        var symb = P1.symbol("");
        console.log(symb);
        var nam = P1.name("");
        console.log(nam);
    });   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Contract at : https://etherscan.io/address/0x080eb7238031f97ff011e273d6cad5ad0c2de532#code

I need to call the balance function from web3

Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/my-key.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting this error in all browsers but Chrome.

Comment: "web3": "1.0.0-beta.34" seems to fix the error